# Tensorflow R-CNN very small object detection - optimal configuration for Scale and Aspect Ratio?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Using Faster R-CNN with Resnet-101, I am trying to detect small objects in a fairly large image. 
The size of the objects is typically 20x20 pixels, the image might be 2300x1700.

I'm currently using the following configuration for scale/aspect ratio:

```
first_stage_anchor_generator {
  grid_anchor_generator {
    scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
    aspect_ratios: [0.25, 1.0, 2.0]
    height_stride: 8 
    width_stride: 8
  }
```

What would be optimal values for scales and aspect_ratios in order to improve very small object detection?

Secondly, scale is also used in [grid_anchor_generator](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/anchor_generators/grid_anchor_generator.py). Could someone please explain which scale is used where (grid_anchor_generator or the .config file) and how the two are related?

Comment: See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047638/tuning-first-stage-anchor-generator-in-faster-rcnn-model), I think the answers there should help you.